# Selecting dropdown with python, beautifulsoup and mechanize

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape data from a what seems to be an ajax webapage. The data auto refreshes every second.

http://daytonama.clubspeedtiming.com/sp_center/livescore.aspx

I can't seem to work out if I'm selecting the correct dropdown or if the page is then changing to the data I need to scrape.

Thanks

```
!/usr/bin/env python
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
#import html2text
import time

# Set credentials
venue = "sp" # Manchester (ma), Milton Keynes (mk), Sandown Park (sp), Tamworth (ta)
track = "3" # Manchester (3), Milton Keynes (1)

# Open new browser
br = mechanize.Browser()

# Target live timing page
resp = br.open("http://daytona"+ venue +".clubspeedtiming.com/sp_center/livescore.aspx")
html = resp.read()

# Grab live data table
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")

# Select track layout
select_node = soup.findAll('select', attrs={'name': 'ddlTrack'})

if select_node:
    for option in select_node[0].findAll('option'):
        print ''
        #print option.text

br.select_form( name = 'form1' )
br.form['ddlTrack'] = [track]

grid = soup.find("div", { "id" : "grid" })
print ''.join(map(str, grid.contents))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually ajax calls are triggered by asynchronous requests with JS running on the target web page

As far as i know mechanize.Browser is not a real browser, it cannot execute and understand javascript, it cannot send asynchronous requests.

In my opinion that is the reason the page you actually trying to input to BS4 is not really loaded, that's why you cannot select.

I can think of two option:

1. Use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or [`phantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/)(headless) as a browser.
2. Analyze the network and try find out what requests the webpage is doing and then just simulating the ajax requests, instead of trying to load the whole page

Comment: This makes perfect sense as targeting the div which wraps around the table won't even show an empty table either... Obviously since it's not loaded by the JS yet.

Thank you! I at least now have an alternative plan of attack!